# Let $G:=(\Bbb Z,*)$ where $a*b:=a+(-1)^ab$ for any $a,b\in\Bbb Z$. Show that $G$ is a group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G:=(\Bbb Z,*)$ where $a*b:=a+(-1)^ab$ for any $a,b\in\Bbb Z$. Show that $G$ is a group.

But, in my solution, $G$ is not a group. Group operation is not associative.

$a$ must be even integer for associative. Am I wrong?

I am new in algebra, i would appreciate it if you help.

Comment: To prove associativity, you need to check all possible cases of $$(a * b)*c = a*(b*c)$$ $a$ could be even or odd, $b$ could be even or odd and $c$ could be even or odd: this gives 8 cases to check. You have checked only the case when all numbers are even, and rejected all other cases: but you didn't actually check them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the operation is the sum if the first "factor" is even and the difference if the first "factor" is odd. This means that there are four cases to consider for $a$ and $b$ in verifying associativity (the parity of $c$ doesn't matter).

- Case 1: $a$ and $b$ are both even.

  In this case, $(a*b)*c=(a+b)*c=a+b+c$ since $a$ and $a+b$ are even. Also, $a*(b*c)=a*(b+c)=a+b+c$ since $b$ and $a$ are even.
- Case 2: $a$ is even and $b$ is odd.

  In this case, $(a*b)*c=(a+b)*c=a+b-c$ since $a$ is even and $a+b$ is odd. Also, $a*(b*c)=a*(b-c)=a+b-c$ since $b$ is odd and $a$ is even.
- Case 3: $a$ is odd and $b$ is even.

  In this case, $(a*b)*c=(a-b)*c=a-b-c$ since $a$ and $a-b$ are odd. Also, $a*(b*c)=a*(b+c)=a-(b+c)=a-b-c$ since $b$ is even and $a$ is odd.
- Case 4: $a$ and $b$ are both odd.

  In this case, $(a*b)*c=(a-b)*c=a-b+c$ since $a$ is odd and $a-b$ is even. Also, $a*(b*c)=a*(b-c)=a-(b-c)=a-b+c$ since $b$ and $a$ are odd.

In all four cases, $(a*b)*c=a*(b*c)$, so the operation is indeed associative.

The identity element is zero since $0*a=0+a=a$ (using the sum since $0$ is even) and $a*0=a \pm 0=a$ (regardless of the parity of $a$).

Finally, the inverse of any even integer $a$ is $-a$ since $a*(-a)=a+(-a)=0$ (using the sum since $a$ is even) and $(-a)*a=(-a)+a=0$ (again, using the sum since $-a$ is even). On the other hand, the inverse of any odd integer $b$ is $b$ itself since $b*b=b-b=0$ (using the difference since $b$ is odd).

Hence, $G$ is a group (but not an abelian group, since distinct odd integers do not commute).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, associativity holds.
\begin{align*}
a \ast (b \ast c) &= a + (-1)^a b + (-1)^{a+b} c  \\
(a \ast b) \ast c &= a + (-1)^a b + (-1)^{a + (-1)^a b} c  \text{.}
\end{align*}
These are only equal if $(-1)^{a+b} = (-1)^{a + (-1)^a b}$, so when 
$$  a + b \cong a + (-1)^a b \pmod{2}  $$
or, what is the same, 
$$  b \cong (-1)^a b \pmod{2}  \text{.}  $$
This is evidently true when $a$ is even.  When $b$ is even, $0 \cong 0$.  Finally, when both are odd, $1 \cong (-1) 1 \cong 1$.

So $(\Bbb{Z}, \ast)$ is an associateve algebraic structure.  It might be a group (if the remaining group properties hold).

Comment: I don't think that's correct.  The two quantities are equal if and only if $b$ and $(-1)^ab$ have the same parity, which they always do.  I think you've proved that associativity holds.

Comment: @RobertShore : Was editing when your comment came in.  Seems I've already addressed your concern.

Comment: $$(-1)^a b \equiv (+1)^a b \equiv b \pmod 2$$ proves associativity. The identity is $0$, while the inverse of $x$ is $(-1)^xx$. So this is indeed a group.

Comment: @Crostul : Agreed.  I'd delete my answer if there were a correct one.

Comment: @EricTowers Just edit your answer to say that yes, associativity does hold and it'll be fine.

Comment: @EricTowers The first line of your answer still says that associativity fails.

Answer (score 1):

It's associative by $\,(a\!*\!b)\!*\!c-a\!*\!(b\!*\!c) = \left[{(-1)^{\large\color{#0a0}{a*b}}\!-(-1)^{\large\color{#0a0}{a+b}}}\right]\!c = [0]c = 0 $

because the exponents have equal parity $\ \color{#0a0}{a\!*\!b} = \underbrace{a\!+\!(\color{#c00}{-1})^ab\equiv \color{#0a0}{a\!+\!b}}_{\textstyle\color{#c00}{ -1}\,\equiv\, 1\ \ \ }\pmod{\!2}$